# java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast akka.actor.Status$Success$ to akka.actor.Status$Success

Tags: akka, spray, spray-dsl

I am facing a weird exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast akka.actor.Status$Success$ to akka.actor.Status$Success
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3094) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$mapTo$1.apply(Future.scala:405) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
```

Where the problem is the trailing $ - something like inner class or so ..

My code follows:

```
  post {
    authenticate(BasicAuth(pifUserPasswordAuthenticator _, realm = "bd pif import api")) {
      user =>
        entity(as[Array[Byte]]) { e =>
          val resp = pifImportService.ask(PifTransactions("storeId","dob",e)).mapTo[akka.actor.Status.Success]
          complete {
            resp
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

Because of my actor is replying as follows:

```
  Try(kafkaProducer.send(payload)) match {
    case Success(_) =>
      log.debug(s"$storeId - $dob - sending payload sucessfully sended to kafka")
      sender() ! akka.actor.Status.Success
    case Failure(throwable) =>
      log.debug(s"$storeId - $dob - sending payload attempt failed $throwable")
      sender() ! akka.actor.Status.Failure(throwable)
  }
```

Am I missing any trick or am I using a wrong name here?

thx

Comment: In addition to the answer below you need to decide what your answer should be. Then you put the type of the answer into the `mapTo`.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I understand that I order to propagate the error I need to send akka.actor.Status.Failure, but for success I need Success message. I understood the mapTo as if success than mapted else Failure.

Comment: It's somewhat explained in the chapter about the ask pattern: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.11/scala/actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `sender() ! akka.actor.Status.Success`

`akka.actor.status.Success` is a case class requiring one argument. Looks like that you've replied not with a class instance, but with a partially-applied Success.apply(_) function, which is not you've planned to do, I believe:

```
case Success(_) =>
  sender() ! akka.actor.Status.Success(storeId)
```